# htaccess Ignoring directory and its subdirectories

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have the following in my htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(mailinglist)/.*$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

I basically want to remove htaccess from hitting that last line if I am in the mailinglist directory.

This only works for items in the root of the /mailinglist directory. Once I go deeper like /mailinglist/w/1 it breaks and hits that last rewrite rule. How do I stop it from processing that last rewrite rule if I am in the /mailinglist directory.

The reason is I have a different set of htaccess in that directory and I do not want this htaccess to control it.

Comment: Thanks to Jon and Drew! The problem I have now is when I go 2 subdirectory deep in the mailinglist directory this conditional does not apply anymore. I am still learning REGEX on HTACCESS and not sure what to add to make it recognize many subdirectories.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(mailinglist)/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

I just switched the checking for `mailinglist` to be a RewriteCond.  The condition will only rewrite to index.php if the URI doesn't begin with `mailinglist`.

Comment: When I go 2 directories deep ie `http://www.example.com/mailinglist/w/1` it then hits the RewriteRule. How do I prevent it to hit that RewriteRule if it is in the mailinglist directory?

Answer (score 0):

The conditions are being applied to the wrong rule, You need to swap around your rules:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(mailinglist)/.*$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Conditions only apply to the immediately following rule, so the 2 `!-f` and `!-d` conditions are being misapplied to the passthrough, while the `index.php` rule is missing those conditions.