# .htaccess & WordPress url rewrite that shows /subdirectory/username but serves /subdirectory/

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdirectory

I have a unique issue with a WordPress site I am working on.  My client would like a promotion where people get "customized" or "vanity" urls, but all the urls just go to the same WordPress page.

With WordPress pretty urls enabled, the url that needs to display in the address bar looks like:

**example.com/subpage/username**

However, it will just be serving this page:

**example.com/subpage/**

The closest solution [I found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12396894/htaccess-ignoring-directory-and-its-subdirectories) suggested I add something like line 6 to the .htaccess code below.  This works in the way that it redirects to **example.com/subpage/** but does not keep the username in the url.  I'm stuck on how to do that. Here is my .htaccess code as it is now.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^survey/. /index.php?p=370 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that it's WP in the background, you'll be better off adding a Rewrite Rule using a plugin:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule

Quoting the docs:

> #### Example
>
> Let's assume you are creating a "Nutrition" page for showing nutritional information. This page uses a custom template and takes two variables, food and variety. Instead of passing ugly querystring variables to the page, you can set up a rewrite rule to create some custom pretty URLs. See below...
>
> ```
> add_rewrite_rule('^nutrition/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?','index.php?page_id=12&food=$matches[1]&variety=$matches[2]','top');
> ```

Comment: Thank you Dennis, I got this woking

Comment: I added this to the theme's funtions.php file and it did nothing at first. `add_rewrite_rule('directoryname/([^/]+)/?$', 'index.php?page_id=IDHERE', 'top');` I found another article that suggested I flush the WP rules cache and then it worked! [link](http://disruptiveart.com/blog/wordpress-custom-url-rewriting/)